# Push objects to array with plugin serializeObject

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I am using [this jQ plugin](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object) for serializeObject().

I am facing problem that I want to make JSON request as follow

```
[
  {
    "name": "",
    "address": {
      "street": "",
      "number": "",
   }
  },
  {
    "name": "",
    "address": {
      "street": "",
      "number": "",
   }
 }
]
```

So I use

```
var form = $('form').serializeObject();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(form),
```

problem is that following inputs are not allowed becasue "key" must start with string, but this is unwanted in this case

```
<input id="name-1" name="[0][name]" type="text"/>
<input id="name-2" name="[1][name]" type="text"/>
```

Any idea how to done this task?

Comment: Thy do you call the name like this? you could send name in different way like you did with ID.

Comment: beacuse plugin need it this way for automatic serialize of whole form input

Comment: You can change name format in server.

Comment: yes that is true, im just trying to find out if it is possible without server-side modification